# How to execute a Powershell Commands from my linux system?

Tags: powershell

I want to administrate my Windows AD server from a Linux system. Currently I am trying with winrm ruby gem to execute powershell command from Linux system and it's works. winrm gem supports plaintext, Kerberos/GSSAPI, or SSL authentication. But now I am not able to configure the authentication with SSL. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add what specifically you have tried and what errors you may of received to your question pls.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [PowerShell Server](http://www.powershellserver.com/), which enable connect to Powershell from SSH. It should be exactly what you need.